# SSG5 Firewall Chrome ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH Workaround?

Tags: ssg5

We have an environment in which we have about a dozen SSG 5 Firewalls.  We administer these using the https web interface and have done so for several years.  Chrome is generally the browser we like to use but no longer supports earlier ciphers and we have not found any workaround as yet.

Obviously one solution is simply to upgrade all of our firewalls, which we fully expect to do within the next two years.  In the meantime, we use Firefox to administer them and have no difficulty with that approach.

However, our concern is that Mozilla and other browser authors will follow Google’s lead and remove support from their browsers for these earlier ciphers.  Although we’re retaining the current version of Firefox to mitigate such a scenario, it would leave us in a precarious position that we don’t want to be in.

Answer (score 1):

Use VMware Workstation, VirtualBox, or whatever you like to build a VM you can run on your workstation(s) with a version of the browser(s) that will allow you to manage your firewalls until you can upgrade the firewalls.

Answer (score 1):

Change the cipher to a supported version on your SSG5

From the SSG5 web GUI, do the following:

1. Go to menu option Configuration --> Admin --> Management
2. Change your cipher to 3DES-SHA1
3. Click Apply